# Syntax to concatenate a variable with static html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to build up a bit of HTML using a mix of razor variables and static content.

Here is where I get stuck: I have a counter variable in my view called `section_counter`.  I want to use that in the ID of the image tag I'm building.  However unlike with `<% .. %>` notation I'm used to, I'm just not able to do what I need.

```
<img alt="section" id="@section_counter_Section" src=""..... etc
```

I need the id to look like `3_Section`.  However if I leave a space between the variable and the word `_Section`, the value retains that space (`3 _Section`).

If I use the `<text>` hint, I get this:

```
<img alt="section" id="3<text>_Section</text>" src="
```

In my generated HTML. What am I missing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try putting your variable in brackets. (An [explicit code nugget](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx))

```
<img alt="section" id="@(section_counter)_Section" src=""
```

Comment: there it is, first time I've had to use that one. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, if it solved your problem please remember to resolve your question by selecting an accepted answer.