# How to concatenate .png to the a href

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code inside my asp.net MVC view:-

```
 <a href="~/Content/uploads/@item.ID.ToString()" + ".png"><img class="thumbnailimag" src="~/Content/uploads/@item.ID.ToString()" + ".png"  /></a>
```

but I am unable to concatenate the `.png` to my `href & src` . can anyone advice please ?
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Syntax to concatenate a variable with static html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000990/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to wrap the code in parentheses, as [explained here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx). No need to call `.ToString()` then:

```
href="~/Content/uploads/@(item.ID).png"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are not closed properly.

```
href='@string.Format("~/Content/uploads/{0}.png", item.ID)'
```

Complete Code

```
<a href='@string.Format("~/Content/uploads/{0}.png", item.ID)'><img class="thumbnailimag" src='@string.Format("~/Content/uploads/{0}.png", item.ID)'  /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, declare `fileName` outside of the href (IMO makes it more readable)

```
@{
   var fileName = item.ID.ToString() + ".png";
}
<a href="~/Content/uploads/@fileName"><img class="thumbnailimag" src="~/Content/uploads/@fileName"  /></a>
```